# Mono Droid onClick event not found

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android

I have the following layout:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Hello"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="Foo"
/>
```

And this in my Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "LayoutTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    }

    public void Foo(View v)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(v.Context, "Bar", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

When I debug this in the emulator the app crashes when I click MyButton with the following excerpt in the log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  507): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  507): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method    Foo(View) in the activity class helloworld.Activity1 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'MyButton'
E/AndroidRuntime(  507):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2059)
E/AndroidRuntime(  507):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/AndroidRuntime(  507):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
E/AndroidRuntime(  507):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(  507):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>MonoDroid does not support registering events in this way.</s>

You need to hook up the events yourself in your activity's OnCreate.

**Update:**
As an update, MonoDroid does now support this: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni/#_ExportAttribute_and_ExportFieldAttribute

Comment: Then what would be the point of the android:onClick attribute?

Comment: If you are writing in Java, it does as you expect.  In MonoDroid, it has no implemented function.

Comment: I see. Thanks.  Would there be documentation on what MonoDroid doesn't support?

Comment: Voting up this response. Wish I had seen this info elsewhere before spending time on this.

Comment: As an update, MonoDroid does now support this: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Java_Integration?highlight=export#ExportAttribute_and_ExportFieldAttribute

Comment: @jpobst I'm kind of a MonoDroid noob...how exactly would that enable you to register events as described in the question?

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out: just throw an [Export] attribute above the onClick methods and make sure to add a reference to  Mono.Android.Export in your project.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to an `[Export ("javamethodname")]` attribute on the `onClick` methods and a reference to `Mono.Android.Export`, you also need

```
using Java.Interop;
```