# How can you handle subclassed view events without instantiating every instance in the activity?

Tags: event-handling, xamarin.android, subclass

In my first MonoDroid app I've subclassed TextView so I can display a border around each view ( [Android - Way to appear bordered text on the TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026873/android-way-to-appear-bordered-text-on-the-textview) ), managed to add it to my layout XML ( [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml) ), and get around NullReferenceExceptions due to MonoDroid's lowercasing of Android namespaces ( [Avoiding a NullReferenceException when creating a custom Android UI element from subclassed TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496383/avoiding-a-nullreferenceexception-when-creating-a-custom-android-ui-element-from) ).

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is handle touch events in each BorderedTextView.

I know I can get each view using FindViewById<> and create a delegate to handle each view's Click event.

```
BorderedTextView currentDate = FindViewById<BorderedTextView>(Resource.Id.currentdate);
currentDate.Click += delegate {
    Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(this, "CURRENT DATE tapped", ToastLength.Long);
    toast.Show();
}

BorderedTextView startTime = FindViewById<BorderedTextView>(Resource.Id.starttime);
startTime.Click += delegate {
    Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(this, "START TIME tapped", ToastLength.Long);
    toast.Show ();
};
```

[image]  [image]

Taking that one step further, I can create a common method in BorderedTextView to handle clicks (but I still have to instantiate each BorderedTextView).

```
// In Activity's OnCreate
BorderedTextView currentDate = FindViewById<BorderedTextView>(Resource.Id.currentdate);
currentDate.Click += delegate {
    BorderedTextView.HandleClicks(this);
}

BorderedTextView startTime = FindViewById<BorderedTextView>(Resource.Id.starttime);
startTime.Click += delegate {
    BorderedTextView.HandleClicks(this);
};

// In BorderedTextView
public static void HandleClicks(Context context)
{
    Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(context, "BorderedTextView tapped", ToastLength.Long);
    toast.Show();
}
```

Since the number of BorderedTextViews is going to vary and I'd like to handle the click events without having to instantiate each view in the activity's OnCreate. I thought I could do something in the layout XML file with the android:clickable and android:onClick attributes.

```
<mbta.BorderedTextView
    android:id="@+id/currentdate"
    android:text="CURRENT DATE"
    android:textSize="15pt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="HandleClicks"/>
```

But it turns out MonoDroid doesn't support registering events in this way ( [Mono Droid onClick event not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726763/mono-droid-onclick-event-not-found) ).

I've currently experimented with SetOnClickListener and the view's OnTouchEvent event without success (using info from the Events and Listeners section on Xamarin's [API Design](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/api_design) page).

What I'd like is a way to handle every BorderedTextView click event with a single method in the BorderedTextView class without having to instantiate each view in the Activity's OnCreate. Is this possible in MonoDroid or am I simply trying to do something that the tool won't support at this time.

Thanks in advance.

Update - 12.16.11

jpobst's suggestion to hook up event handlers in BorderedTextView's constructors worked.

```
public BorderedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
{
    this.Click += delegate {
        HandleClicks (context);
    };

    this.Tag = this.Text;
}

public BorderedTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
{
    this.Click += delegate {
        HandleClicks (context);
    };

    this.Tag = this.Text;
}

public BorderedTextView(Context context) : base(context)
{
    this.Click += delegate {
        HandleClicks(context);
    };

    this.Tag = this.Text;
}
```

And here's the actual method to handle the click

```
public static void HandleClicks(Context context)
{
    string typeName = ((Type)this.GetType()).Name;
    stirng selected = "Selected " + (string)this.Tag + " (" + typeName + ")";

    Toast.MakeText(context, selected, ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just hook up your event handler in the BorderedTextView constructor?

Comment: Thanks, that worked (a case of me not seeing the forest for the trees, making things more complicated than they needed to be). Have updated question with solution.